# Clozure common lisp. How to list subdirectories on windows?

Tags: windows, lisp, ccl

My folder looks this way

```
c:/bar/
c:/bar/dir1
c:/bar/dir2
c:/bar/00.txt
c:/bar/02.txt
```

I can list files

```
(directory "c:/bar/*.*")
(#P"c:/bar/00.txt" #P"c:/bar/01.txt")
```

but have a problem listing subdirectories

```
(directory "c:/bar/*")
NIL

(directory "c:/bar/*/")
NIL
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: probably best asked on the Clozure CL mailing list. http://clozure.com/mailman/listinfo/openmcl-devel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:directories t` in CCL:

```
(directory "C:/bar/*.*" :directories t)
```

However, if you want to write implementation independent code (e.g. a library you want to share), you should probably heed Vsevolod's recommendation, and use a compatibility layer like `cl-fad`.

Comment: And to get the directories only - (directory "C:/bar/*/" :directories t)